# PIL- is possible to give PIL a binary object rather than a file handle?

Tags: python, python-imaging-library

I can get PIL to work with files:  `Image.open('example.jpg')`.

Is there a way of doing the same with a jpg thats created in code, without writing that jpg to the HDD:  `Image.open('binaryObject')`.

I've tried giving PIL the binary output of a function, and I have tried (but probably got the implimentation wrong for) the parser attribute: http://effbot.org/imagingbook/imagefile.htm

```
from PIL import Image
f = open(image.jpg, "rb")    
f_data = f.read()
try:
    Image.parser()
    parser.feed(f_data)
    parser.close()
    print "OK"
except:
    print "fail"
```

My HDD can't keep up!

Answer (score 2):

Instead of writing to disk, write the image to memory with a `StringIO` object:

```
try:
    from cStringIO import StringIO
except ImportError:
    from StringIO import StringIO

fake_file = StringIO()
fake_file.write(f_data)
```

Now, you can pass `fake_file` to `Image()` as a file handle.

Comment: Oh, very cool! thanks! Another new thing to play with - I appreciate your time.

Comment: @JayGattuso: Take a look at [gnibbler's answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13356468/464744). I don't work with PIL often.

Comment: hohum, that didn't go as planned... and either I'm a dunce or gnibbler's answer has gone awol..

Comment: @JayGattuso: He deleted it. It said: Perhaps you can use one of `Image.fromarray` / `Image.frombuffer` / `Image.fromstring`.